# Use datetime in pythran

Tags: python, c++, pythran

I'm working with **pythran**, a Python to c++ compiler http://pythran.readthedocs.io/

Can we use datetime or any other way to use in pythran function a date or a time info ?:

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.now()
```

I get:

```
$ pythran ccompile.py 
ccompile.py None None
CRITICAL I am in trouble. Your input file does not seem to match    
Pythran's constraints...
E: Attribute 'now' unknown (ccompile.py, line 13)
```

Comment: what is `pythran`? besides, your question makes little sense can you explain what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datetime` module is not supported by pythran, as can be deduced from the error message. Workarounds are:

- call `datetime` from the python code and pass the result to the pythranized function
- fill an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/pythran/issues) of the project.